# Problem on invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A\in M_{mn}(\mathbb{k}),B\in M_{nm}(\mathbb{k})$. Prove that $I_m-AB$ is invertible iff $I_n-BA$ is invertible.

My thoughts:

I know that if $A$ and $B$ are matrices of order $m$ by $n$ and $n$ by $m$ respectively where $m\leq n$, then $|AB-cI_m|=c^{n-m}|BA-cI_n|$. From this if $I_m-AB$ is invertible then $1$ is not a eigenvalue of $AB$, therefore $I_n-BA$ is also invertible.

Comment: Next time please use MatJax for the formulas. It's easy, just wrap 'em between $ symbols!

Answer (score 3):

If $I-AB$ is not invertible, then 1 is an eigenvalue of $AB$,

so $ABx=x$ for some $x\ne 0$.

Then $BA(Bx)=Bx$ with $Bx\ne 0$ since otherwise $x=0$, so

1 is an eigenvalue of $BA$ and therefore $I-BA$ is not invertible.

Since we can interchange the roles of A and B,

we get that $I-AB$ is invertible iff $I-BA$ is invertible.